# Wordpress plugin download-after-email issue

Tags: plugins

I am using free version of "download-after-email" wordpress plugin. I am able to download pdf docuemnt using my personal email id (hotmail as well as gmail ids). But when my client tried to download a document, it showed error message - "Please make sure all fields are filled in correctly." I also checked it at my end and got same error.

What could be the issue? Please help!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to contact the plugin support area for this question. That's the proper place - this place doesn't do plugin support.

Comment: Have you read the plugin support like this one: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/please-make-sure-all-fields-are-filled-in-correctly/